# XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... mp4

Tags: javascript, apache

I embedded a **third-party** javascript script into a page. It's for tracking the events from a video on the page. But I get an error:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://third-party_url.com/file.mp4. 
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
 Origin 'http://fast.wistia.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know there're the solution to that error but they, probably, would be applicable if it were  my own script. How do I fix the error?

UPDATE:

I added this to my

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://fast.wistia.net"`
```

to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my_domain.com` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Including

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/js/jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js />
```

solved my problem check it out.